# How to add scramble support for Open VPN for Android Client

Tags: openvpn

Obfuscation is known to bypass restrictive firewalls and DPI of some ISPs. I am wondering why this hasn't been implemented officially in the client, given that its open source.

This has been done for some mac and windows clients (and perhaps android clients which are mostly close sourced).

After a bit of digging, I came across a scramble/xor patch here: https://github.com/clayface/openvpn_xorpatch/blob/master/openvpn_xor.patch.

Is there a way to add scramble support for Open VPN client, either by simple decompiling and recompiling or building the client from scratch?

There is another client: [VPN Client Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.colucciweb.vpnclientpro&hl=en&gl=US), which has scramble support but requires a subscription, ideally was looking for a free option to simply to this patch in order to connect to obfuscated servers.

Comment: I was in a country where government could sniff OpenVPN using DPI techniques.  So on a rooted device, I've been using [`shapeshifter-dispatcher`](https://github.com/OperatorFoundation/shapeshifter-dispatcher) and [`obfs4proxy`](https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4) to tunnel OpenVPN through obfuscated/scrambled protocol. No need to modify the OpenVPN client. Just run a separate process as listening proxy and send OpenVPN towards it. I used to run the process as an `init` service to fully automate the process.

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into it, if you have a guide that will be appreciated

Comment: No sorry I don't have a guide. It was a pure DIY project. But currently I don't have a working setup either. You can find guides for Linux though. They are applicable to Android as well for the most part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that, there is an [ics-openvpn-xor project](https://github.com/lawtancool/ics-openvpn-xor) on github by lawtancool.

> This is the latest stable release of
> https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn compiled with added support for
> the Tunnelblick obfuscation patch.

APK releases can be found [here](https://github.com/lawtancool/ics-openvpn-xor/releases)